# How to efficiently use Kafka in place of Sidekiq for background Job in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-kafka, jobs, sidekiq, ruby-kafka

Currently, I am to using sidekiq for background jobs in rails app. Now I want to use Kafka for the same using consumer-producer mechanism. For that I am using `ruby-kafka` and producing messages **asynchronously**.

**My approach**: In the `perform` method of `MyNewJob < ApplicationJob` Job I am calling `produce` method of Kafka and when `consumer` receives the message, I execute the actual piece of code(which was previously executing inside perform method) inside a new class method of `MyNewJob`.

It is working as expected. I want to confirm, **is it the right approach** or not? If not then what should be the right approach?

**Pseudo Code:**

I will call my job using any of `MyNewJob.perform_now` or `MyNewJob.perform_later` etc.

my_new_job.rb

```
class MyNewJob < ApplicationJob

  queue_as TestMixin::QUEUE_NAME

  rescue_from(App::ServerError) do
    retry_job wait: Rails.application.config.retry_interval
  end

  def perform(paylaod)
    #producing message asynchronously
    producer = kafka.async_producer
    producer.produce(payload, topic: "topic_name")
  end

  def self.run_job(payload)
    #code to executed previously written inside perform method above.
  end

end
```

consumer.rb (pseudo code)

```
  #client consumer topic subscribe logic and then start consuming.
  consumer.each do |message|
    MyNewJob.run_job(message.payload)
  end
```

I am also thinking of **another approach** where I skip bringing `ApplicationJob` class into existence and directly produce message in Kafka instead of calling Job.

Please confirm.

Edit 1:
I am using `ruby-kafka` with asynchronous producer (`kafka.async_producer`).

Comment: Are you using ``ruby-kafka``? Is it set up to use an asynchronous producer or synchronous (default)?

Comment: @rmlockerd , yes I am using `ruby-kafka` with asynchronous producer (`@kafka.async_producer`).